# One terraform policy document for multiple queues

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have multiple queues with different names and one iam policy document that I want to use for all those queues. Is it possible to apply a single policy for all of them without having to list all queue names under resources section?

queue example

```
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "first_queue"{
  name = "first_queue"
  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.sqs_all.json}"
}
resource "aws_sqs_queue" "second_queue"{
  name = "second_queue"
  policy = "${data.aws_iam_policy_document.sqs_all.json}"
}
```

iam policy document

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sqs_all" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow",

    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = ["arn:aws:iam::${var.deploy_account}:user/some_user"]
    }

    actions = [
      "SQS:SendMessage",
      "SQS:DeleteMessage",
      "SQS:ReceiveMessage",
      "SQS:GetQueueAttributes"
    ],
    resources = [
      "FIXME",
    ]
  }
}
```

So I want to replace FIXME from the above code with something, so that policy would apply for both queues from above, but do it without listing the queues, since there a lot of queue in actual terraform script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use templates. The syntax is different depending on your terraform version. You can check it [here for 0.11](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/template/d/file.html) or [here for 0.12](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html)

You will need to create a file with the following content in some place in your project. Let's say that you'll name it `sqs_policy_template.tpl`:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowSQSInvocation",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "SQS:SendMessage",
        "SQS:DeleteMessage",
        "SQS:ReceiveMessage",
        "SQS:GetQueueAttributes"
      ],
      "Resource": [${queue_arn_list}]
    }
  ]
}
```

Inside your terraform template, you use the following resource to render the template and *compile* it:

For version 0.11:

```
data "template_file" "sqs_policy" {
  template = "${file("sqs_policy_template.tpl")}"
  vars = {
    queue_arn_list = [arn1, arn2, arn3]
  }
}
```

For version 0.12 is a little bit more simple. You just call the function:

```
templatefile("sqs_policy_template.tpl", [arn1, arn2, arn3])
```